# In Rust's backend, with http GET request, how to get array in query parameter

Tags: http, rust, backend, rust-axum

Array data has 4 forms in query parameter:

1. `?id=1&id=2`
2. `?id=1,2`
3. `?id[]=1&id[]=2`
4. `?id[0]=1&id[1]=2` \

`serde` and `serde_qs` can only support 3&4 ("duplicated key" when use 1, and "need sequence but found string" when use 2). I'm developing API which can only accept 2. So I have to create an intermediary struct to get every array value by String, and then split it into `Vec<String>` and move to new struct. Obviously, it's ugly, inefficient and difficult to maintain.

`serde_qs` have some issues about it, but it seems that its owner haven't resolve it yet. Are there any beautiful way to **deserialize query params into a certain struct**?

In addition, I'm using `axum` to develop a RESTful API. But without good deserialize tool, it's very hard to develop complex GET requests. If there are any functions work better than `serde_urlencoded` (which is executed at `axum::extract::Query`), we could create `CostomQuery` to easily deserialize more data structure.

Answer (score 0):

(2) you can handle reasonably easily via serde's [`(de)serialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with) and a custom (de)serialisation function, or [serde_with's fromstr support](https://docs.rs/serde_with/3.4.0/serde_with/struct.DisplayFromStr.html) (and a newtype implementing `FromStr`):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "from_seq")]
    id: Vec<u8>,
}

fn from_seq<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<u8>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s = <&str>::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    s.split(',')
        .map(|i| u8::from_str(i))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
}
```

=>

```
id=1,2 => Ok(Foo { id: [1, 2] })
```

(1) I think you need a full blown hand-implemented deserializer on your type to correctly handle duplicate keys, I've not seen a third-party crate which handled that use case (`serde_with` as a hook to trigger an error on duplicate *map* entries, but nothing to control the behaviour of duplicate struct fields), although it's possible I missed it.

Comment: I published a crate to deserialize form style parameter depend on FromStr trait. It's more generic. [Here](https://crates.io/crates/deserialize_form_style_query_parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I published a crate to deserialize form style parameter depend on FromStr trait. It's more generic. [Here](https://crates.io/crates/deserialize_form_style_query_parameter). It can easily deserialze `Vec<T: FromStr>` and `Option<Vec<T: FromStr>>`, and any T impl FromStr (which also supported by `serde_with`).